# How to add an app config to an exe if I can’t open it in VS or even manage?

Tags: visual-studio, app-config

I must add an `app.config` file to an exe file which I have no control of.
Note: I can’t open the `exe` in VS. I only have the executable.

Comment: You meant Visual Studio by VS? Add this tag please, if it so. And `.net` if you use it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need visual studio to create app.config file, you can create it in any text editor and place it in the same folder as your executable and that's all.

The file name for your app.config should be like this `AppName.exe.config`